# how can i see how much time is left to the clock?

Tags: python, time

here's my code:

```
import time
import datetime
from playsound import playsound

print("pls use the 24 hour time scale")
alarmHour = int(input("what time do you want to wake up? "))
alarmMin = int(input("what min do you want to wake up at? "))
while True:
    if(alarmHour == datetime.datetime.now().hour and
       alarmMin == datetime.datetime.now().minute):
       while True: 
           playsound("D:/Soul and Mind - E's Jammy Jams.mp3")
       print("time for some coffee sleepy head")
       break
    else:
        print("i'm not there yet")
        time.sleep(10)
```

it's just a simple alarm clock that when it hit's a certain time it plays a sound.
and untill then every 10sec it prints "i'm not there yet" and i want to make a count down to the alarm. right next to the ("i'm not there yet"). how can i do that?

Answer (score 0):

You could do it with a simple math calculation.

```py
while True:
    if(alarmHour == datetime.datetime.now().hour and
       alarmMin == datetime.datetime.now().minute):
       while True: 
           playsound("D:/Soul and Mind - E's Jammy Jams.mp3")
       print("time for some coffee sleepy head")
       break
    else:
        hoursLeft = alarmHour - datetime.datetime.now().hour
        if hoursLeft <= 0:
            hoursLeft += 24
        minsLeft = alarmMin - datetime.datetime.now().minute
        if minsLeft < 0:
            minsLeft += 60
        print (f'{hoursLeft}h{minsLeft}m left till the alarm')
```